# How do I factor out React components that require the parent's attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

I'm using React with Formik and I'd like to do a refactoring.

The `Field` component below is passed a lot of properties and I'd like to define a wrapper around it that configures `Field` using `errors`, `touched`, etc. props but without defining stuff like the `helperText` time and time again, i.e., only pass in required props and derive the rest.

However, once I take the `Field` component out, I won't be able to reference the required props (like `errors`, `touched`, etc.) anymore. How do I get these in conveniently?

```
export const MyForm = ({ initialValues, validationSchema, handleSubmit }) => {
  <Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    render={({
      errors,
      status,
      touched,
      isSubmitting,
      handleBlur,
      handleChange,
      handleSubmit,
      values
    }) => (
      <Form>
        <Field
          fullWidth
          id="firstname"
          name="firstname"
          component={TextField}
          error={Boolean(errors.firstname && touched.firstname)}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          helperText={errors.firstname && touched.firstname && String(errors.firstname)}
          value={values.firstname}
        />
      </Form>
    )}
  />;
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't use functional components in this example in my opinion. For composition use the regular syntax [Here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: @JoséSalgado, thanks for your comment! Why wouldn't you use a functional component? I'm not storing state within `MyForm`, right?